# permutation of elements inside the list of list

Tags: python, list, nested, permutation

I have a nested list as follows:

```
A = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
```

I need to permute only the elements inside each list.

do you have any idea how can I do this?

Comment: So you just want to shuffle each sublist?

Comment: show the expected output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To shuffle each sublist in a list comprehension, you cannot use `random.shuffle` because it works in place. You can use `random.sample` with the sample length = the length of the list:

```
import random

A = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]

new_a = [random.sample(l,len(l)) for l in A]

print(new_a)
```

an output:

```
[[2, 1, 3], [5, 4, 6], [7, 9, 8]]
```

That solution is the best one if you don't want to modify your original list. Else, using `shuffle` in a loop as someone else answered works fine as well.

Answer (score 4):

You can do something like this:

```
import random
A = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]

for x in A:
    random.shuffle(x)
```

Comment: Thanks. It really helped me.

Answer (score 0):

Use permutations from itertools:

```
from itertools import permutations
A = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
out = []
for i in A:
  for j in permutations(i):
    out.append(list(j))

print out
```

OUTPUT:

```
[[1, 2, 3], [1, 3, 2], [2, 1, 3], [2, 3, 1], [3, 1, 2], [3, 2, 1],
 [4, 5, 6], [4, 6, 5], [5, 4, 6], [5, 6, 4], [6, 4, 5], [6, 5, 4],
 [7, 8, 9], [7, 9, 8], [8, 7, 9], [8, 9, 7], [9, 7, 8], [9, 8, 7]]
```